# Яндекс Радио это Нейронная сеть или Рекомендательная система?

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект, яндекс-радио

Какой принцип заложен в Яндекс Радио? Это Нейронная сеть или Рекомендательная система?

Comment: Одно другому не мешает. Вполне может быть рекомендательная система на основе нейронной сети.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А если погуглить?

> ### цитата с блога яндекса за 4 июня 2015 года
>
> В основе Яндекс.Радио лежит рекомендательная технология, разработанная
>   в Яндексе. Мы назвали её Диско, отчасти в честь музыкального жанра
>   (впервые Диско применили в Яндекс.Музыке), а отчасти по созвучию с
>   английским discovery — «открытие чего-то нового», словом, которое
>   очень точно отражает суть технологии. Диско учитывает ваши действия
>   (факты прослушивания и пропуска треков и оценки «нравится» и «не
>   нравится»), составляет картину музыкальных предпочтений и, сверяясь с
>   ней, определяет, какую музыку пускать в эфир станции.

Теперь зайдём на наш любимый вики:

> ### цитата со статьи в википедии о сервисе яндекс.радио
>
> Действует машинное обучение на основе истории прослушиваний:
>   пользователь может создать свою собственную радиостанцию, которая
>   будет ориентироваться на его предпочтения.